# PDO BindValue doesn't work but works with direct paste

Tags: mysql, pdo, bindvalue

So I have some code

```
//passed as function param
$clause[2] = "'2016-09-09' AND '2016-09-09'"

$sql = "SELECT {$columns} FROM `{$table}` WHERE `{$clause[0]}` {$clause[1]} :clause";
$stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue("clause", $clause[2]);
if ($stm->execute()) {
   return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
d
//echo'd $sql
SELECT * FROM `deliveries` WHERE `delivery-date` BETWEEN :clause
```

If I replace the `:clause` in `$sql` with the raw input, `'2016-09-09' AND '2016-09-09'` then it works fine. As soon as I try to bind it with either :clause or using a `?` then it fails. I have no clue what to do about it :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know the difference between **expression** and **value**? You can only bind values. Nothing else. No table names, no column names, no  some randomly constructed dynamic SQL. It's so trivial that it confuses people. The idea is that you provide nice SQL that works, then you tell MySQL "hey, here I want values", then you put nice placeholders in form of `:param_name` and MySQL obliges, treats the value as string / int and sticks the whole thing to disk. Also, are you aware of `composer` and metric ton of libraries that help you forget about doing this PDO thing manually?

Comment: Thanks for the replies totally cleared up now :) no expressions which I should have realized haha. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Well, I'm glad I helped. Now go build something awesome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind whole expressions like that. Binding values is not just string substitution. You can bind a value in an SQL query **only** where you would normally put a single scalar value. If you need two values for example for a `BETWEEN` predicate, you need two placeholders.

Furthermore, you must not put quotes in your bound values. The fact that a placeholder means exactly one scalar value makes quotes unnecessary.

It looks like you're trying to make a general-purpose function so you can make any conditions you want, and your `$clause` array is supposed to contain the column, the operator, and the value.

You're going to have to write code to format the SQL differently for multi-value predicates like `IN()` or `BETWEEN`:

```
$column = $clause[0];
$operator = $clause[1];
$valuesArray = (array) $clause[2];
switch ($operator) {
case 'IN':
    $expression = "(" . implode(",", array_fill(1, count($valuesArray), "?") . ")";
    break;
case 'BETWEEN':
    $expression = "? AND ?";
    break;
default:
    $expression = "?";
}
$sql = "SELECT {$columns} FROM `{$table}` WHERE `{$column}` {$operator} {$expression}";
$stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($valuesArray);
return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I don't bother to test the return value of execute() because you should just enable `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.